# Fragment list in a Tabhost

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

in mainactivty of my app I set a tabhost with its viewpager , now I would like to create within each tab is a list of custom fragment and that is different for each tab , how can I do ? thanks in advance deposit

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MaterialTabListener {

MaterialTabHost tabHost;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager );

    // init view pager
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // when user do a swipe the selected tab change
            tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

        }
    });

    // insert all tabs from pagerAdapter data
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTab()
                        .setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this)
        );

    }

}


@Override
public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {
    pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {

}

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    public Fragment getItem(int num) {
        return new FragmentText();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 16;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Section " + position;
    }

}
```

}

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#009688"
    />

<it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    app:primaryColor="#009688"
    app:accentColor="#ffc400" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials on this, just google it. In your case I would use [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html).